How to implement OAuth2.0 correctly in React app?
I have been trying to introduce authentication with Google account in my web application
In the following code snippet in useEffect() I initialize the OAuth client and then, when the button is clicked, I should see the response.credential  object in the console. But I see undefined.
const Modal = (props: Props) => {
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const { onClose } = props;
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const rootRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    createContainer({ id: MODAL_CONTAINER_ID });
    setIsMounted(true);
    window.onload = function () {
      window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        callback: handleCredentialResponse,
        use_fedcm_for_prompt: true,
      });
    };
  }, []);

  const handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {
    // const claims = jose.decodeJwt(response.credential);
    console.log(response.credential);
  };
};

I have no idea why I don't get the object, Client ID is correct, initialization seems to work just fine.
Please help me understand the issue

Does using callback: (data) => handleCredentialResponse(data) help?

@tbold no, unfortunately it doesn't
